# Sustained and Sustainable

Tags: word-usage

Is there any difference between the two sentences:

1. The country has achieved sustained economic growth for past decade.
2. The country has achieved sustainable economic growth for past decade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding *-able* makes things *capable*. *To manage* is to *manage* but then *manageable* is something that is *capable of being managed*.

That way, *sustained economic growth...* means maintained at the length of that period without any hassle or interruption.

*Sustainable* with adding *-able* would mean the country has achieved economic growth which is capable of being sustained.

The former shows country's efforts to maintain the economic growth whereas in the latter case, the country has achieved sustainable economical growth but will have to work more to make it *sustained* economic growth.

Try to understand the example I mentioned. If as a class-teacher you get *manageable* batch of pupils (they are mischievous) but then you'll have to try further to make them *managed* batch of pupils. The latter means you successfully managed those who were manageable.